# This app is not listed in the Shopify App Store using shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I am working with shopify and i am trying to integrate "app" using shopify partner but i am getting following error

```
This app is not listed in the Shopify App Store
```

How can i reolve this issue ?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What action are you trying to do that is generating the error?

Comment: Is this still an issue for you?  And is it an app your trying to publish, or is it a "private" app, that you're tring to install on a shop?

Answer (score 0):

The app was removed by Shopify or renamed.